# Wear OS Navigation on Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android-studio, wear-os

I'm using Android Studio to develop an Wear OS standalone application.
Everything is working fine despite the emulator navigation.

When the Watch is started on the following screen I'm not able to simulate the navigation with the mouse (swipe, click, etc nothing works). How can I access the menus or start my app?

[image: Emulator]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A cold reboot from the device solved the problem.
It seems the emulator was finally hanging.